# Crystal Reports changing sorting with custom logic

Tags: sql, sorting, crystal-reports-2008

I need to sort a demand pick list report by BIN_id, but in an odd logic that I am not sure how to handle through crystal reports.  So, bins are going to be [A-J][01-06][01-06], so for example D0306 would be one of the bin numbers. 
The warehouse is set up as so (imagine the middle line of this table is where the warehouse workers will be walking).below is the format

```
A     B

C     D

E     F

G     H
```

What we want them to do is start with the "A" side of the bins, go all they way down to the farthest letter they need (up to G), switch over to the opposite side of the bin they stopped on (so if they only went down to E, they would end up at F and go up and pick from F through B).   What I need to do with crystal reports is get BIN ID'S to sort like the examples below:

EDIT: A batch of orders is going to have BIN_ids that can possibly start with A-G. For example a batch of orders might have bins A0102, B0304, G0304, G0106, E0101, C0106, C0205,  C0404, D0106, D0202.  With this order I would want is sorted as such:

A0102, C0106, C0205,  C0404, E0101, G0304, G0106, D0106, D0202, B0304

EDIT: More examples
if only A and B bins exist in the batch of orders:
    A bins then B bins
if A bins through F bins exists in the batch:
    A then C then E then F then D then B
if C,E,G,D exist in the batch of orders:
    C then E then G then D

And so on and so on.  Basically we want warehouse workers to make a U shape while they are picking through the warehouse.  Start at A, go down to G, switch over to H and go up to B.  This logic isn't complicated, I just have no idea how to go about doing it in Crystal...

Thanks your you help everyone, let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and how you want it ordered?  Your explanation is not 100% obvious.

Comment: Yep yep, sorry about that.  I added an example, let me know if you want some more :)

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is very confusing!!!!

After reading multiple times I understood you want to sort the report in the way you wish to and my solution will be according to this.

You need to manually apply sorting on the filed that is obtained from database so the solution should be:

Group the report according to the required field now when insert group window is appeared then go to tab "Group in Specefied order" and at that tab set the way you want to view the report.

If I am totally out of your problem.. Explain clearly will try to help.